# WDF - filter driver for sandbox

Tags: wdf, filter-driver

I want to intercept file (ReadFile, WriteFile) operations and registry calls of some program. I decided that filter driver will be the best solution. Is it possible to do that from WDF or I need to learn WDM?
Are there any samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, minifilter is the right solution